# I have power at all plugins but when I plug something in it doesn't work an voltages testers goes to 0

Tags: electrical

I have 119.1 volts at all plugins but when I plug in a light the light does not work and the voltage meter reads 0.

Comment: Are all the outlets in question on the same circuit (breaker or fuse), or on different circuits?

Comment: power != voltage, it's voltage*current and you have no current.

Comment: A voltage tester does not draw enough current to check for a complete circuit. It is not the tool for the job.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common failure.
First check your breaker panel for a tripped breaker
To reset it turn it off then back on at the breaker itself.
This cycle resets the breaker.
If the same results:

What you are seeing is phantom voltage.
This is voltage created when 2 lines run parallel snd a voltage is induced on the line OR there is a weak connection at a wire possibly just a bit of carbon creating a path of sorts that provides a voltage but no current.

The most common source of a single circuit having this problem is from backstabbed connections usually at receptacles. A backstab is the push in connection. These have a small contact area and can overheat, arc and now a bad connection.

Working from the breaker panel find the last working receptacle or first non working receptacle, the problem will be in one of these 2 locations.

What you are looking for is a black or white wire in most cases that is loose or broken. There may be significant damage to the wire and insulation or you may find nothing and if you put the receptacle back in everything starts working.

If it starts working like this and there are backstabbed connections it will happen again so it is best to move the connections to screw terminals. If your receptacle only has backstabs a new one can be purchased for under 1.50$ in most of the US
A good one for 3-5$ yes there is a difference in quality.

Make sure to do all work with the breaker off to protect yourself. A broken wire or usually a backstab creates this failure in over ~98% of the cases I have seen as an electrician for 40 years with the exact same symptoms.